# Using JQuery how can I color every other row black?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, css

I don't have a table or ul structure for this but I am using divs to display data.  I need the background color of every other row to be black.  I looked around but most options are for tables or list menus so a bit puzzled as to how to do this.  Any idea?

My structure:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="dataset">
         Thomas Jones
     </div>
     <div class="dataset">
         Edward Jones
     </div>
 <div class="dataset">
         Tommy Lee
     </div>
 <div class="dataset">
         Jenna Haze
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share the html

Comment: No need for JQuery, use CSS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do with with just CSS(3) using `:nth-child(odd)` (or even):

```
div.dataset:nth-child(odd) {
    background: black;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nL54m/1/)**

Comment: +1 And to bring the awesome to IE8 as well, one can use [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com) or [bipen's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18641354/1456376).

Answer (score 5):

i would go with CSS but in case you need it in jquery..then you can use `:even` or `:odd` selector.

try this

```
 $('div:even').css('background-color','black'); // or just background , selects all even divs.
 $('div:odd').css('background-color','black'); //selects all odd divs.
```

**for just those divs having class dataset..add class selector to div. try this**

```
 $('div.dataset:even').css('background','black');
```

Comment: Cheers bipen, I'm pretty sure he wants the `.dataset` class of divs. +1 for your change!

Answer (score 2):

If you must use jQuery for this:

```
$(".dataset").each(function(index){
    if(index%2 == 0)
       $(this).css('background', 'black');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B6XcZ/)

or use `$("div.dataset:even").css('background', 'black');`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B6XcZ/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Use even/odd css3 selector

**HTML**

```
<div>row1</div>
<div>row2</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #fff;
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
    background:red; 
}

div:nth-child(even) {
    background:black; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sheeban/vHGzw/